# Group a (sometimes non consecutive) period of days in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, date, gaps-and-islands

I'm looking for a query that takes mostly consecutive days and groups them together depending on whether they are really consecutive and on the value belonging to that date. I'm using Oracle version 11g.

This is some example data:

```
date          value
2012-01-01    2000
2012-01-02    2000 //(there is no data for Jan 03 for example)
2012-01-04    2000
2012-01-05    5000
2012-01-06    5000
2012-01-07    5000
2012-01-08    2000
2012-01-09    2000
2012-01-10    2000
```

(this is the result of quite a large query)

What I'm looking for would group those days together in periods like this:

```
from_date   to_date     value
2012-01-01  2012-01-02  2000
2012-01-04  2012-01-04  2000
2012-01-05  2012-01-07  5000
2012-01-08  2012-01-10  2000
```

We did manage to formulate a query that does what I want, but it's not a very efficient way, and I'm pretty sure something better/more elegant exists. This is what I'm using now:

```
with temp_table as (
select a.pk_date DATE1, c.pk_date DATE2, a.volume VOL1
from dm_2203 a, dm_2203 c
where a.volume = c.volume
  and a.pk_date <= c.pk_date
  and not exists (select 1 from dm_2203 b
                  where a.volume = b.volume
                    and a.pk_date = b.pk_date+1)
  and not exists (select 1 from dm_2203 d
                  where c.volume = d.volume
                    and c.pk_date = d.pk_date-1)  )
select * from temp_table y
where date2-date1+1 = (select count(*)
                       from dm_2203 z
                       where z.pk_date between y.date1 and y.date2
                         and y.vol1 = z.volume)
order by 1;
```

Does anyone have an idea on how to do this faster and without all the joins? Thanks!

Comment: Which version of Oracle is this?

Comment: I don't understand the logic for your desired output, Why are those two rows the output?

Comment: @Lamak: The set of two rows is not the desired output - the set of four rows is the desired output.

Comment: @Lamak: I removed the lines, to be more clear, but indeed: that was not the desired output, it was what I'm getting when using a normal group by clause

Comment: @MarkBannister: Sorry for not adding it earlier to the question. It's version 11g

Comment: It looks like it's trying to show the volume for each band of data where it's invariant - where day X+1 has the same value as day X.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I thin this should work and also be reasonable efficient (it should hit the table only once)

```
create table t ( d date, v number);

insert into t values (trunc(sysdate), 100);
insert into t values (trunc(sysdate+2), 100);
insert into t values (trunc(sysdate+3), 100);
insert into t values (trunc(sysdate+4), 100);
insert into t values (trunc(sysdate+5), 200);
insert into t values (trunc(sysdate+6), 200);
insert into t values (trunc(sysdate+7), 200);
insert into t values (trunc(sysdate+8), 100);

select min(d), max(d), v
from (
    select d, v, 
        sum( gc) over (partition by v order by d) g
    from (
        select d, v, 
            (case (d - lag(d) over ( partition by v order by d) )
                when 1 then 0
                else 1
             end) gc
        from t
    )
) group by v, g
order by min(d), v
```

Note that if you want to run the logic in an efficient way on a subset of your data, you should add the where clause in the inner most select. Otherwise oracle will have problems to use any index.

Comment: Very nice. Here's the [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/3ecee/6) using the OP's test data and table structure using your code

Comment: thanx for the link to SQL Fiddle. Awesome tool.

Comment: @JensSchauder: This is looking really nice, and I'm trying to adapt it now for my query. I actually have a few more fields than only date & value, but the general idea should be the same. Thanks already!

Comment: @Xuntar, Jens Thanks its actually the first time I used it. I came across it yesterday in this [Meta Question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126472/where-to-put-a-commity-owned-tutorial-for-certain-classes-of-users-for-specific)

Comment: @JensSchauder: Something very strange happens when I test it with my real data. I get the error ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected INTERVAL DAY TO SECOND got NUMBER when I add "g" to the group by function. Without the "g" there's no error, but of course the result is not correct either. Now trying to figure out why this happens...

Comment: @JensSchauder: Apparently storing Dates as Timestamps gives an error when comparing with 1. I had to compare with NUMTODSINTERVAL(1, 'DAY') instead. Thanks for your solution!

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
with cte as (
select pk_date from_date, pk_date to_date, volume
from dm_2203 d
where not exists
(select null from dm_2203 e 
 where d.volume = e.volume and d.pk_date-1 = e.pk_date)
union all
select c.pk_date from_date, d.pk_date to_date, c.volume
from cte c
join dm_2203 d on d.volume = c.volume and d.pk_date = c.pk_date+1)
select from_date, max(to_date) to_date, volume "value"
from cte
group by from_date, volume
```